# Should I use @return self, this or the current class?

Tags: php, documentation, phpdoc, doc

I have a method that return the current object, how do I document this?

```
/**
 * set something
 *
 * @return this
 */
public function setSomething(){
            // ...
    return $this;
}
```

Or should I do `@return self` or `@return Current_Class_Name`?

---

Reason why this question is not "primarily opinion-based" (and should be reopened): conformance to standards and IDE type hinting support.

Comment: related, for static: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5858031/phpdoc-and-late-static-or-dynamic-binding

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`@return Current_Class_Name` will definitely work and is what I prefer.

`@return self` may work ok with some programs too.

`@return this` is bad because this is not a typename.

Comment: "return Current_Class_Name" works best at the moment, as it will allow IDE autocompletion to succeed.

There are feature requests in for phpDocumentor [1] and Eclipse PDT [2] to recognize "return $this".

[1] -- http://pear.php.net/bugs/bug.php?id=16223
[2] -- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=276082

Comment: PhpStorm does support `@return self`

Comment: What if I want to return the subclass but not the base class where I write the method?

Comment: I disagree with this answer, `/** @return $this */` is the only real fluent phpdoc type. While `@return Current_Class_Name` is not fluent and you will notice that when extending the class and calling the function from a child.

Answer (score 52):

There is a [PHP Standards Recommendation (PSR)](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/) currently in draft [(PSR-5) that proposes](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/proposed/phpdoc.md#appendix-a-types) **@return $this** is used in order to indicate that the same instance is returned.

> $this, the element to which this type applies is the same exact instance as the current class in the given context. As such this type is a stricter version of static as, in addition, the returned instance must not only be of the same class but also the same instance.
>
> This type is often used as return value for methods implementing the Fluent Interface design pattern.

This notation is currently used by popular IDEs such as PhpStorm and Netbeans.

Comment: Your answer is misleading because it sounds like this PSR recommends `$this`. I don't think this is true. It simply *allows* it, just like `Current_Class_Name` and `self`.

Comment: Also note that it is `@return $this` not `@return this` as the question asked.

Comment: I use PHP Storm and $this upsets it, whereas self and \Class do not

Comment: Please note that PSR-5 is abandoned.

Comment: @AnthonyB not anymore, for example see this PR https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/pull/1104 and discussion https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/php-fig/W1VyAtoqGQ8

Comment: @sanmai I confirm, PSR-5 is no longer abandoned, it's in [draft](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/#draft) now. Thank your for this point.

Comment: @DavidYell at least since 2018 `@return $this` works better than any other class return type, with proper resolution of any inheritance.

Comment: phpstan (PHP Static Analysis Tool) also prefers `@return $this`

Answer (score 10):

This question is quite old, but I just want to share to everyone!

*AT LEAST* for the ones that uses **NetBeans 8.1**.. this notation makes **code autocompletion to nicely work** at IDE:

```
/**
 * Method that returns $this instance (using late state binding)
 * @return static
 */
 public function iWillReturnMyself ( ) {
     return $this;
 }
```

I say *AT LEAST* for NetBeans8.1 users, but *may work* on older versions and/or others IDEs too =]

Comment: for netbeans 8.2 works too

Comment: This (imo, best option) unfortunately does not work in PHPStorm. "Field `name` not found in static".

Comment: @PeterM PHPStorm supports static here on my version (2018.2)

Comment: Also works for VS Code

Comment: this worked for me on VS code with a static method returning an instance of the class

Answer (score 8):

```
/**
 * set something
 *
 * @return self
 */
public function setSomething(){
            // ...
    return $this;
}
```

You can use "self" type as @param or @return..

PHPDoc recommends 'self' to refer to self in object..

Source: http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/types.html

Comment: This works with subclasses poorly. If the subclass doesn't override it, interpreters do not know that an object with the same subclass must be returned.

Comment: @SOFe `@return static` appears to be supported by PHPStorm.